# Using vue.js how do I make an image as a button which allows me to route another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vKip.jpg)

Hi everyone, I just started learning on HTML/CSS. Basically, as part of my final project, I am being tasked to create a food ordering webpage using vue.js. To be honest(however I am only familiarised on the C/C++ coding), I have been looking on for more guidelines for the project, however, I am unable to learn. I do know some coding stuff in the HTML/CSS/js. However, I am hoping for more advice on how do I make an image go to another page using vuejs/vue router when one clicks into any of the images. Any help here I would appreciate as it can be new learning points for me. I am using the visual studio code for this project.
PS: I have referred to similar posts regarding to mine, but I couldn't understand. Thanks in advance.
Below is my code so far that I have used in the vue file (Which is under Table.vue using vue-router), If you have any questions, do let me know.

Comment: This is a very broad question that has no specific answer.

Comment: @BlueWater86 Hi thank you for replying. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear enough. I am having issues creating an image button and by creating an image button it will continue to direct the user their choice as I am creating a food web application, the first router link i have used as table number at the moment. It will then display the choices available in the cafe. How do I create an image button by starting things off? I have tried to use <td > <b-button> <img src="@/assets/drawable/v1meal.jpg" style="width:80%"></b-button></td>, it does reflect on the web but doesn't on mobile

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, the router can "push" to a route. You can view an example on JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/eooujnwo/). You can also programmatically change the route by using `this.$router.push('/path')` in the component methods called from the `@click` event on your images.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear enough. I am having issues creating an image button and by creating an image button it will continue to direct the user their choice as I am creating a food web application, the first router link i have used as table number at the moment. It will then display the choices available in the cafe. How do I create an image button by starting things off? I have tried to use <td > <b-button> <img src="@/assets/drawable/v1meal.jpg" style="width:80%"></b-button></td>, it does reflect on the web but doesn't on mobile